# Getting all the same values in keras model.predict

Tags: python, keras

I am using keras LSTM layer and my output predictions are very similar to each other. They are not different by more than 2 units. Here is my code:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(5, activation='relu', input_dim=5))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

prediction = model.predict(x_scaled_test, batch_size=128)

Gold_prices = prediction*(max(Input['Gold Price']) - min(Input['Gold Price'])) + min(Input['Gold Price'])
print(Gold_prices)
```

My output is:

```
[[ 1288.44628906]
 [ 1289.5736084 ]
 [ 1289.57202148]
 [ 1287.84240723]
 [ 1287.92114258]
 [ 1287.15515137]
 [ 1287.58068848]
 [ 1287.59069824]
 [ 1287.55432129]
 [ 1286.953125  ]
 [ 1286.72021484]
 [ 1285.88684082]
 [ 1285.25085449]
 [ 1285.2557373 ]
 [ 1285.06494141]
 [ 1285.65588379]
 [ 1285.36767578]
 [ 1285.87121582]
 [ 1286.1427002 ]
 [ 1286.52526855]
 ...
```

I am using relu and sigmoid function for my activation functions.

Comment: Why are you using sigmoid for your output activation?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6447), you can try the following things:

1. reduce your batch size (when you have small dataset)
2. decay your learning rate (after many training epoches)
3. scale your data set (and rescale after prediction)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using resression you should use linear activation on your output layer

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(5, activation='relu', input_dim=5))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))
```

Comment: This does not work, as I'm not doing regression. I am trying to predict a time series.

Comment: Yes you are because you are not doing classification.

Comment: Yes CORRECT. Anyway how to use keras to predict a number?